# c++ matrix class dynamic array argument

Tags: c++, arrays, class, matrix

I want to implement a Matrix class. I coded an array of arrays of pointers. When I set the values of each element of the array to 0 with a for loop, it works fine (apparently). But when I try to declare a function of my class (setvalues) to take the values of a 1D array and store them in the matrix, theres a problem with the arguments. I am not sure how to declare a function that takes a dynamic array as argument.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Matrix{
    int rows, columns, numE;
    double *mData=new double[numE];

    public:
    double** matrix;
    Matrix(int,int);
    setmatrix();
    setvalues(double);
};

Matrix::Matrix(int x, int y){
    rows=y;
    columns=x;
    matrix=new double*[columns];
    for(int i = 0; i < columns; ++i){
            matrix[i]=new double[rows];
    }
}

Matrix::setmatrix(){
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
            matrix[i][j]=0.0;
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<endl;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::setvalues(double mData[]){
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
            matrix[i][j]=mData[i];
        }
    }
}
int main(){

Matrix AA(2,2);
AA.setmatrix();
//AA.setvalues();
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
          cout<<AA.matrix[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }

cout<< AA.matrix << endl;
delete [] AA.matrix;
return 0;
}
```

PS: I don't want to use vector or smart pointers. Also if you have any feedback about my code regarding functionaity, readability and if you know a smarter way to do it please tell me.

Comment: `delete [] AA.matrix;` This should be done in the `Matrix` class.

Comment: "PS: I don't want to use vector or smart pointers." why?

Comment: Expected behavior?

Comment: Well, it should reproduce the behavior of a matrix..each element should be accessed with two subindexes, and then it should support the arithmetic operations on matrices like sum, comparison etc